# Getting time/date from Sqlite into Gnuplot

Tags: database, sqlite, gnuplot

I like the idea of Sqlite but I'm more comfortable with PostgreSQL, Mysql, even MS Access or Oracle.

I've got something written by someone else which generates Sqlite databases that include a date/time field and I want to get those into a format that Gnuplot can understand.  Both Sqliteman and Sqlite browser show the field is an integer, and it looks like a unix time_t when I just query it, except it's 3 digits longer, like 1444136564028.

It doesn't have to be done by piping sqlite3 into Gnuplot, and it doesn't have to use the unixepoch/%s time format. I just can't find any examples of converting the Sqlite time fields in a query.  One example "SELECT strftime('%s','now')" works, but when I replace now with a field in a real query it doesn't work. All the examples I find seem to use immediate/literal values, not fields from queries.

And can Sqlite use a tablename.fieldname format or does it have to be select fieldname from tablename?

Answer (score 2):

Unix timestamps use seconds; using milliseconds is a common Java quirk:

```
> WITH MyLittleTable(d) AS (VALUES(1444136564028))
  SELECT datetime(d / 1000, 'unixepoch') FROM MyLittleTable;
2015-10-06 13:02:44
```

Comment: So they call it unixepoch but it isn't really.  Java bloat, grrr :)

Comment: select datetime(timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch') from networkmonitor; since it's the Android app Network Monitor involved. If you choose a raw database output you get an Sqlite database.  Fairly useful, really.

Comment: So back to the real thing: <br>select datetime(timestamp/1000,'unixepoch'), cell_signal_strength_dbm from networkmonitor where gsm_full_cell_id=131779032 order by timestamp;<br>I live in an area with bad cell service, but it's also my main internet connection.